Can I pretend that Spearman's = Pearson's correlation coefficients for meta analysis?
How legitimate it is to pretend that Spearman correlations are Pearson correlations?
I am currently working on a systematic review and meta-analysis examining the correlation of Test A with Test B (gold standard). My meta-analysis involves pooling correlation coefficients from various studies, but I've encountered a methodological challenge: some studies report Spearman's correlation coefficients, while others report Pearson's.
Given the different assumptions and calculations underlying Spearman's and Pearson's coefficients, I'm seeking advice on the best approach to combine these in a meta-analysis (which involves Fischer's Z transformation for Pearson's and then re-convert to coefficient for interpretation; should I do so for Spearmans? how to do so?)
If anyone has experience with statistical software or packages that offer solutions for such issues, your recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Could you access the raw data and recalculate the correlation coefficients yourself?

unfortunately thats not an option, the raw data are not available

No, you cannot treat Pearson and Spearman correlation coefficients as though they are the same thing. Since you cannot access the raw data, I think your best best would be to analyse the two separately i.e. do two separate meta-analyses for Pearson's and for Spearman's.

thank you for your insights @mkt! from a clinical/statistical point of view, what added value does this have? I am thinking of doing a meta analysis for Pearson only and excluding spearmans, what do you think?

@helplessstudent147 Sure, you can just do Pearson's if you don't think there's much to be gained from doing Spearman's as well. The main point is that if you do them both, do them separately.

One issue is that the same transformation cannot be applied to Spearman as to Pearson. However a helpful answer on this site show how to compute an appropriate confidence interval. Once you have done that you can proceed using both of the coefficients. I would regard it as mandatory to include a moderator to distinguish them and to stress in the write-up that all this does rely on some further assumptions.
